# How to easily DB dump to heroku's DB

Tags: ruby, database, heroku, command-line, import

I have a local db full of data that i want to push to the Heroku's DB in order to populae it.

What is the best way/tools o realize this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that ports your current DB into a seed file, then run the seed file using `heroku run rake db:seed`

Answer (score 0):

First dump your local database to a dump file:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

Replace `myuser`, `mypassword`, and `mydb` with your username, password and database name.  If there is no password set, leave out the `PGPASSWORD=mypassword` part.

Next, you must place the `mydb.dump` file in a publicly accessible location, so upload it to an FTP server or Amazon S3 bucket (for example).

Then on your local machine run:

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/mydb.dump' HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL -a appname
```

Replace `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL` with the URL for your app's database.  If you don't know the URL, you can find it with `heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRES`.  Replace `https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/mydb.dump` with the URL where you uploaded the dump file.  Replace appname with name of your app as defined in Heroku.